# Ring Homomorphism (mapping of unit element) between a ring and an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R and S be two rings with unit elements. Let us assume that the unit element of R is $1_R$
and the unit element of S is $1_S$. Let $\phi$ : R → S be a ring homomorphism. Show that if S is
an integral domain, then $\phi$ ($1_R$) = $1_S$.

Note: $\phi$($1_R$) $\neq 0_S$ (Zero element in S)

I want to prove this **via contradiction specifically** and have proceeded as follows:

$\exists y \in S \ \ s.t.$  $ y \ \phi(1_R)  \neq \ y $

Then-

$ y \ \phi(1_R)- y  \neq  0_S $

I am stuck here and don't know how to proceed ahead with this proof using contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi(1_R) \neq 1_S$, then $\phi(1_R)-1_S \neq 0_S$ and $\phi(1_R) \neq 0_S$ but
$$(\phi(1_R)-1_S)\phi(1_R) = \phi(1_R) - \phi(1_R) = 0_S,$$ that is, $\phi(1_R)-1_S$ and $\phi(1_R)$ are zero divisors in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prove it by contradiction. Note that
$$1_R 1_R = 1_R,$$
so
$$\phi(1_R 1_R) = \phi(1_R) \phi(1_R) = \phi(1_R) = \phi(1_R) 1_S,$$
and since $S$ is an integral domain, the cancellation laws implies that $\phi(1_R) = 1_S$.

Comment: I was requested to show this using contradiction specifically and hence I was a bit clueless. Is it possible though?